# Mean comparison using Johnson distribution

Tags: r, mean

I have to use Johnson distribution to see how different means are when modifying the skewness value (.3 in the code below):

```
library(moments)
library(SuppDists)

k <- 500

parms <-JohnsonFit(c(0, 1, .3, 6))
sJohnson(parms)
poblacion <- rJohnson(1000, parms)

mu.pob <- mean(poblacion)
sd.pob <- sd(poblacion)

p <- vector(length=k)
for (i in p){
  muestra <- poblacion[rJohnson(1000, parms)]
  p[i] <- t.test(muestra, mu = mu.pob)$p.value
}

a_teo = 0.05
a_emp = length(p[p<a_teo])/k
sprintf("alpha_teo = %.3f <-> alpha_emp = %.3f", a_teo, a_emp)
```

If I change the .3 for 1, I got different values for mean and standard deviation, but I got exactly the same empirical value for alpha: 1.000. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code.

- Instead of `for(i in p)` it should be `for(i in seq.int(k))`;
- The way you sample/resample, `poblacion[rJohnson(1000, parms)]`, is wrong. The index `rJohnson` is not integer and it will not index `ppoblacion`. The correct ways should be any of the ways in the `for` loop below.
- Though not wrong your calculation of `a_emp` is too complicated, see the equivalent `mean(p < a_teo)`.

And here is the complete code corrected.

```r
library(moments)
library(SuppDists)

set.seed(2024)

k <- 500

parms <-JohnsonFit(c(0, 1, .3, 6))
# sJohnson(parms)
poblacion <- rJohnson(1000, parms)

mu.pob <- mean(poblacion)
sd.pob <- sd(poblacion)

p <- numeric(k)
for(i in seq.int(k)){
  # muestra <- sample(poblacion, 1000, TRUE)
  muestra <- rJohnson(1000, parms)
  p[i] <- t.test(muestra, mu = mu.pob)$p.value
}

a_teo <- 0.05
a_emp <- length(p[p<a_teo])/k
mean(p < a_teo)
#> [1] 0.042
sprintf("alpha_teo = %.3f <-> alpha_emp = %.3f", a_teo, a_emp)
#> [1] "alpha_teo = 0.050 <-> alpha_emp = 0.042"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-10 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Instead of the `for` loop above, you can use `replicate`. From [`help("replicate")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html), my emphasis:

> `replicate` is a wrapper for the common use of sapply for repeated evaluation of an expression (which will usually involve **random number generation**).

```
p <- replicate(k, {
  muestra <- rJohnson(1000, parms)
  t.test(muestra, mu = mu.pob)$p.value
})
```

Note that with `replicate` you do not need to create `p` with the required length beforehand, it will be `replicate`'s return value.